# Check if item exists in list and push value into it — in one shot

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check if item exists in list, and if it is, push into it a value.

All this, is for avoid from run on the list twice.

Because if I do something like this:

```
if (Params.Any(p => p.Name == "Phone"))
    Params.Where(p => p.Name == "Phone").First().Value = phoneValue
```

I am run on the list twice. the first time in the `any` and the second time in the `where`.

So actually I want to do the both above lines — in one shot.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you're going to be looking up parameters by name, you should probably be storing them in a key based lookup, i.e. a `Dictionary`, rather than whatever you're storing them in now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var parameter = Params.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Phone");
if (parameter != null) parameter.Value = phoneValue;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `FirstOrDefault` as follows:

```
var result = Params.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Phone");
```

then check if the value is not null and then set the property:

```
if(result != null) result.Value = phoneValue;
```

This way you don't have to enumerate twice over the source.

Answer (score 2):

A traditional for/foreach loop would be better here as `Any` and `Where` will have to iterate the collection two times which might not be what you want in terms of performance.

So do a simple foreach:

```
foreach(var item in Params) 
{
  if(item.Name == "phone")
  {
     item.Value = phoneValue;
     break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another posible solution is use [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

```
public static class ParametersExtensions
{
    public static void SetValue(this List<Parameters> ListParameters, string name, string newValue)
    {   
        var parameter = ListParameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(name)); 
        if (parameter != null)
            parameter.Value = newValue;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as belows:

```
Params.SetValue("Phone", phoneValue);
```

Comment: The OP wants to assign a value; with your solution this seems impossible to me.

Comment: @UweKeim sorry my english level is not so good. ¿What is the meaning of OP?

Comment: "OP" = "[Original Poster](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/op_original_poster.html)". The guy who asked the question that you answered .